# Writing automated tests for data migrations

Tags: django, database-migration

Is there a straightforward way to unit test data migrations in Django?

Let's say I have a `CharField` with fixed choices like `London` and `Tokio`, but I want to replace the enum with a foreign key to a dedicated model so that I can store additional information about each city (e.g. the country).

My approach to writing the migration would be:

- Add nullable `ForeignKey` field
- Perform data migration that inserts a value into the `ForeignKey` field that reflects the value of the `CharField`
- Make the `ForeignKey` non-nullable
- Remove the `CharField`

But how would you test this with `TestCase`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's surely doable. I think you could make use of the tools Django tests itself with: [`MigrationExecutor`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/migrations/executor.py#L12) and [`MigrationTestBase`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/tests/migrations/test_base.py#L15). Here's [a sample](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/tests/migrations/test_executor.py#L25) of how to invoke migrations in your tests.